# JPA Hibernate startup trying to drop the foreign key twice

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm getting an error when the application starts up on one foreign key relationship when I set Hibernat to `hbmddl = create`

The parent entity is this one - the base class doesn't have a conflicting attribute.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attributes_text_values")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "attributeValue_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@DiscriminatorValue("TEXT")
public class TextAttributeValue extends AttributeValue {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attributeValue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TextAttributeValueLabel> labels;
```

Then the related class is defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attributes_text_value_labels")
public class TextAttributeValueLabel extends AbstractAuditableEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    private AttributeValue attributeValue;
```

At startup I get an error in the log:

```
22:23:40.640 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger 109 logStatement - alter table attributes_text_value_labels drop foreign key FK_7yali4vrura8hbmpj2h6gyf4n
22:23:40.653 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger 109 logStatement - alter table attributes_text_value_labels drop foreign key FK_jn9v2dt1vcr1bf14p48wxgpnv
22:23:40.667 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger 109 logStatement - alter table attributes_text_value_labels drop foreign key FK_35dt165s920hrh03kupm0b9n7
22:23:40.683 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger 109 logStatement - alter table attributes_text_value_labels drop foreign key FK_35dt165s920hrh03kupm0b9n7
22:23:40.694 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport 426 perform - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table attributes_text_value_labels drop foreign key FK_35dt165s920hrh03kupm0b9n7
```

Then similar error when it tries to add the foreign key again.

I noticed for some reason it's trying to drop the FK twice.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The many-to-one side must be `TextAttributeValue` type because it represents a bi-directional association between `TextAttributeValue` and `TextAttributeValueLabel`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attributes_text_value_labels")
public class TextAttributeValueLabel extends AbstractAuditableEntity{

@ManyToOne
private TextAttributeValue attributeValue;
```

If you want to manage an abstract type collection in `TextAttributeValueLabel` you could define the one-to-many side on `AttributeValue` entity instead. But it doesn't look that is your situation.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Cheers.